# Как выполнить функцию после выполнение предыдущей ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как выполнить функцию при завершении предыдущей на ReactJs

Answer (score 1):

передать первую во вторую как функцию первого порядка

```
let callback = function(){
    console.log("hi from callback")
}

function myFunc(callable){
   // do something
    callable()
}
```